# Apply Dynamic CSS on a angular component based on object value

Tags: css, angular, html

Is there any way in angular, html or css to dynamically apply CSS based on object value:

HTML:

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let obj of objs">    
 <span class="(value according to variable)">
   {{ obj.n }}
 </span>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

CSS:

```
.first {
  color: #db4437;
}

.second {
  color: #32cd32;
}
```

What I want to do is,
if *obj.n* is *red*, I want *first* as the class of *span* tag
and *second* => otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or

```
<span [class.first]="obj.n === 'red'" [class.second]="obj.n !== 'red'">{{obj.n}}</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `[ngClass]` and evaluate expression

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let obj of objs">    
  <span [ngClass]="(obj.n ==='red')? 'first' : 'second'">
  {{ obj.n }}
  </span>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

[Take a look at this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whbfq8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: It is not working, **Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)** I think there is some mistake in span tag ending with **"**.

Comment: @HarshilShah : The answer you have selected is crude and has redundant code of `[class.first]` and `[class.second]`. Not a recommended angular way. Upto you. :)

Comment: I have different classes for different type of values of the obj. That's why I'm choosing another answer. Otherwise yours is working just fine, too.